# How can I count a duplicated entry in different days as a single entry?

Tags: sql, count, subquery, having-clause

I have the following structure:

```
MemberID
Year
Month
Day
```

Everyday, when an user logs in, in the activity will appear something like this:

```
'1337', '2020', '09', '01'
```

This thing occurs everyday and what I want to do is to count a member as an active member. If his memberid is displayed in 5 different days, I want to include him to the ,,active members" category. I have a lot of entries and for each memberid I want to do this and count all of them in just one variable.

```
'1337', '2020', '09', '01' 
'1338', '2020', '09', '01' 
'1339', '2020', '09', '01' 
'1340', '2020', '09', '01' 
'1341', '2020', '09', '01' 
'1337', '2020', '09', '02' 
'1338', '2020', '09', '02' 
'1339', '2020', '09', '02' 
'1340', '2020', '09', '02' 
'1341', '2020', '09', '02' 
'1337', '2020', '09', '03' 
'1338', '2020', '09', '03' 
'1339', '2020', '09', '03' 
'1340', '2020', '09', '03' 
'1341', '2020', '09', '03' 
'1337', '2020', '09', '04' 
'1338', '2020', '09', '04' 
'1339', '2020', '09', '04' 
'1340', '2020', '09', '04' 
'1341', '2020', '09', '04' 
'1337', '2020', '09', '05' 
'1338', '2020', '09', '05'
```

So what it will count -> 2, because only 1337 and 1338 logged in 5 dif. days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an overall count of active numbers, you can use two levels of aggegation:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (select memberid from mytable group by memberid having count(*) > 5) t
```

The subquery filters users that have more than 5 occurences in the table. Then the outer query just counts them.

Comment: this works thank you :) can you tell me how can I do it also for current month only ? this one brings overall which is also good, I tried myself to put also a criteria for month but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Get all members that appear at least 5 times:

```
> select MemberID from TableName group by MemberID having count(*) >= 5;
```

Get count of all these members:

```
> select count(*) c from 
> (select MemberID TableName group by MemberID having count(*) >= 5) t;
```

For a given month (7 in the example):

```
> select count(*) c from 
> (select MemberID TableName where month = '07' group by MemberID having count(*) >= 5) t;
```

Comment: For the month I tried too the same query -> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where month = 08 group by MemberID having count(*) >= 5) t LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

Comment: How did you define the table? Check the type of your column, strings need to be enclosed in quotes '08'.